# How to create GitHub Personal Access Token without client ID/secret, and without trying to clone a protected repo?

Tags: python, github, oauth, credentials

Is there a way of generating a **personal access token** for GitHub using a username and password only?
I'm trying to carry out all of this functionality from a Python app.

I'm aware, of course, that one can create a PAT using GitHub's website, but I want to avoid that approach.

I'm also aware that seemingly anything related to making use of OAuth from an application seems to require a client ID/secret - this isn't something I feel like many users would be aware of when they first want to set up a functional account's credentials to be stored and used by the application in the future, for a specific repo.

An option which really interests me is the GitHub login prompt which comes up whenever a person tries to do a `$git clone` for a repo that they've never accessed before.
By editing the .gitconfig settings, you can make the credential.helper output to a file (or maybe even a database) as a store, in plaintext. Obviously that's not secure.. it's better to store in a Manager, but lets say my intentions are to have access to the token itself.. all of that **seems like a pretty good way to get access to the token** **as a variable**, and with only a username and password to generate it.

The problem with this solution however is that the prompt only seems to come up as a result of `$git clone`, which is quite invasive. If it were to want to make use of the feature in a /register endpoint for example, I wouldn't want for any clones to occur at that stage.

**For the record, I completely acknowledge that even doing something like `echo "url=https://USER:PASSWORD@github.com/OWNER/REPO.git" | git credential approve`  would work as a non-invasive way of storing credentials, however, this doesn't generate a token... which is the theme of the question.. and also this doesn't validate that they're correct credentials either (until corrected by a $git clone's resulting GitHub user/password prompt)**

tldr; how do I get that little prompt to appear for my repo, without a $git clone?
is there a non-invasive way of generating a token, having it be storable as a variable, without the need to $git clone, or knowing any client ID/secrets? (by all means, if I could somehow access the ID/secrets through the API, I could go down the road of authenticating my app with OAuth approach.. as I know it allows you to have access to the token as a variable, but I feel like ID/secret wouldn't be the type of thing the GitHub API could expose.)

Comment: git doesn't have personal access tokens.  should this git tag become a git _hub_ tag?

Comment: of course, apologies!